# Shell commands from vim

Tags: shell, vim

What is the best approach of using shell commands from vim? I know about the possibility of `!shell_command`. But this doesn't know all commands e.g.
`export OSTYPE; make install` So I have to run it outside vim. Is there better approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't know all commands"? The example you gave runs fine in vim.

Comment: no better method, :!your command here should work for everything.

Comment: if it can run outside with your xterm or something like that, it should work in vim. Another method: run a shell instead and do whatever you want, then close it, you will be returned to vim automatically.

Comment: @John Cromartie. When I run it outside vim it ends without errors, in vim it ends with errors.

Comment: @xralf:  Are you trying to execute both the export and the make in the same :! command?  I wonder whether that's the problem.  Do they execute properly if you break them into two separate :! commands?

Comment: Hm, it seems that `export` doesn't work like that from vim.

Comment: I tried `!export OSTYPE` with OK and then `!make install` with errors. There was some problem with path which had `\\` signs in name instead of '/'. I tried `shell` command as eugene suggested. On first attempt (I don't remember which it was) it ended with errors and on second attempt it was OK. Now I'm running `!make install` from vim without errors.

Comment: @xralf: The problem in commands execution may lie in the difference of interactive and non-interactive shells: in non-interactive shell aliases are not allowed and some initialization steps are skipped. It should not make difference for your particular example unless you aliased `export` or `make`. Also note that executing `!export ...`, then `!command` does not makes any since shell where you exported variable has already gone when you execute `!command`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can start a shell from Vim using the [`:sh`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html) command. When the shell exits
(after the `exit` command or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) you return to Vim. The name for the shell command comes from the [`shell`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27shell%27) option.

For terminal Vim (on unix-like systems) you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend Vim and get back to the shell from which it was run. To resume the Vim process, use the `fg` command.

Comment: Is it possible to have shell in one split or tab and file in another? I sometimes need to see shell and source file at the same time. I'm using `tmux` but that's bad to mix tmux command and vim commands for navigation between splits.

Comment: @xralf You can try [Conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/). It is slow, does not work well with unicode and won't update buffer that is not in current window (until you switch to it), but that is the best you can do with current vim capabilities. You may also try [screen](https://github.com/ervandew/screen) plugin which can send keystrokes to other screen/tmux window from within vim.

Answer (score 26):

I know this is a bit late, but my preferred approach is suspending the vim process (Ctrl+z). You return to your shell/bash command prompt.

Then execute whatever command(s) you like.

Return to vim by typing `fg`